# Isn't $(0)$ a prime ideal in a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have read in multiple places that a field $K$ has a Krull dimension of $0$. How is this true? Isn't $(0)\subset K$ a prime ideal in $K$? Obviously $K$ is an integral domain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, but $K$ is not a prime ideal, so the inclusion $0\subset K$ does not count towards the dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Krull dimension is defined to be the *length* of the longest chain of prime ideals. In other words, a ring $R$ is said to have a Krull dimension $n$, if the longest possible chain of prime ideals 
$$ \mathfrak{p}_{0}\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_1\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_n$$
has length $n$.

Since $0$ is the only prime ideal in a field (in fact the only proper ideal in a field), it follows that Krull dimension of a field is 0 (since there is no way to have $0\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}$ for another prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$).

**Added.** In case it wasn't made clear, $K$ itself is not a prime ideal of $K$, because by definition prime ideals **must be** proper ideals.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I had thought that if there is a single prime ideal in the chain, then the length of the chain is one.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: You are welcome. Yeah I think I had that confusion at some point too. Thing to take from this: The length of the chain is always one less than the number of terms in the chain.